# In octave, how to print a number up to d decimal places, where d is a value that the user inputs

Tags: octave

I want to print a variable `val` up to `d` decimal places, where `d` is input by the user. The value of `d` is not known while writing the program.

I tried the following:

```
printf ('%.df',val);
printf ('%.{%i}f',d,val);
```

It doen't seem to work though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the special formatspecifier `*` to indicate a *formatting* argument. E.g.:

```
octave:1> val = exp(1)
  val =  2.7183
octave:2> decimalPlaces = 3;
octave:3> fprintf('The value to 3 sig digits is: %.*f \n', decimalPlaces, val) 
   The value to 3 sig digits is: 2.718
```

The [matlab documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html#bq05n2x-1) has a good section on this.

Comment: Cool beans, I like that. :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to generate the format string with the proper value first; it won't be replaced within `fprintf`:

```
d = 5;
val = 7.123456789
fmt_str = ['%.' num2str(d) 'f'];   % fmt_str = '%.df', d replaced with number
fprintf(fmt_str, val);
```

Comment: actually, there *is* special syntax to include variables for formatting specifiers themselves. (see my answer)